# Print the fingering for the note on a saxophone

Tags: code-golf, music

Your challenge is, given a series of notes, print the fingerings that minimize the amount of movements you need to make (explained below).

My not standard way of transforming fingerings to text:
The `|` line separates the left and right hand. Use `1` for the index finger, `2` for the middle finger and `3` for the ring finger. Use `a-d` for the right hand to represent the side keys played by the pinkies (and just `a` and `b` for the left hand).

An example for low A#/Bb:
[image: Poorly scaled saxophone fingering chart]

which would be written as `123d|123b`.

The side keys, which are hit with the part of your hand between the thumb and index finger, are labeled as `e`, `f`, and `g`.

In addition, there is a little key between the right hand's `1` and `2` used for playing `Bb`. This is called the `i` key.

The octave key is labeled `o`

These are the fingerings (note that `b` means flat, not the note `B` which is uppercase):

```
A#3 or Bb3: 123d|123b
B3 or Cb4: 123c|123b
B#3 or C4: 123|123b
C#4 or Db4: 123b|123b
D4: 123|123
D#4 or Eb4: 123|123a
E4 or Fb4: 123|12
E#4 or F4: 123|1
F#4 or Gb4: 123|2
G4: 123|                // Note that the | is still necessary
G#4 or Ab4: 123a|
A4: 12|
A#4 or Bb4: 12|g OR 1i| OR 1|1 OR 1|2
B4 or Cb5: 1|
B#4 or C5: 2| OR 1|f
C#5 or Db5: |  OR o3|  // No fingers down for first fingering
D5: o123|123
/* All fingerings from D5 - B#5/C6 are the same as the lower octave
   but with the octave key (prefixed with o) */
C#6 or Db6: o|
D6: of|
D#6 or Eb6: oef|
E6 or Fb6: oef|e
E#6 or F6: oefg|
```

**Input**:
A series of notes separated by semicolons.

**Output**:
A series of fingerings separated by semicolons.
If there is more than one way to finger a certain note, the program must chose the fingering that minimizes *distance* from its neighbors. If it is the only note or there is a tie, you may output any fingering.

A fingering's *distance* from another is how many fingers you would have to lift/press to change the note.

Example: `12| --> 1|` has a distance of 1 because you have to lift finger 2.
Example: `12|g --> 12|` has a distance of 1 because you only have to lift one side key.

Test cases:

```
C#5;D5;C#5 --> o3|;o123|123;o3|
```

**Bonus**: -100 if your program takes an audio file (probably midi) as input and outputs the fingering corresponding to the notes played.

Comment: Is C#5 o13| (as in the test case) or o3| (as in the spec)?

Comment: Sorry it should be o3

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, <del>528</del> 525 bytes (ouch!)

Not the prettiest code in the world, but I think it works. Calculates the shortest overall distance by trying all possible fingering combinations, so also not the most efficient.

```
from itertools import*
def f(x,y):a,b=x.split('|');c,d=y.split('|');return len(set(a)^set(c))+len(set(b)^set(d))
print(";".join(min(product(*["zd|zb zc|zb z|zb zb|zb z|z z|za z|12 z|1 z|2 z| za| 12| 12|g&1i|&1|1&1|2 1| 2|&1|f |&o3| oz|z oz|za oz|12 oz|1 oz|2 oz| oza| o12| o12|g&o1i|&o1|1&o1|2 o1| o2|&o1|f o| of| oef| oef|e oefg|".replace('z','123').split()["C D EF G A B".find(n[0])+" #".find(n[1:-1])+12*int(n[-1])-46].split('&') for n in input().split(';')]),key=lambda x:sum(f(x[i],x[i+1]) for i in range(len(x)-1)))))
```

Not many tricks. Saved a bit by a string-replace on "123". Simplified distance calculation by doing each half separately. Note name to pitch calculation is fairly tight but should be able to golf the rest down.